# select a range to copy and paste in another cell if a condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim word As Variant
Dim range As Variant


If cells(5, [6]) = "Bulk Density" Then
range = ("A3:K11")


For Each word In range
        If word = "Moisture Content" Then
            [M20] = word.Offset(0, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
        Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Hi im trying to select a range based on cell `f5`. And then if that word is met in `f5` i want to select a certain range (`A3:K11`) where i can copy data from and move it to another cells. For example if cells `f5` contains "Bulk density" i then want to copy the moisture content value in the range of cells (which is not always in the same row) and then paste the value into `M20`. The copy and paste of the value works when i put the range in automatically but when i want it select the range itself the word variable is always empty and im not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreicated thanks max

[image]

Comment: Hello, It's hard to determine the logic, there would be no reason to loop through A3:K11 as the word will only be in column F...Can you filter column F for Bulk Density & Moisture Content, then loop through the filter cells? ,I am assuming you want to do this for all the groups.

Comment: Hi davesexcel yes that correct, so should i determine the range to be F3:F11 in this case then?

Comment: Yes, in your description, it looks like you are trying to find the word "Moisture Content" and get the result next to it. If you are hard coding the range, =vlookup() would be all that is required.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for your response.  im trying to write a vba because there is about 400 test i have to go through each day. My logical was i can filter through the csvs and get the information in rows which i can string across to my master tracking sheet. i keep getting a object required  [M20] = word.Offset(0, 1) and im unsure why. i want to get this part of the code to work as then i just need to replicate it for all the other parts and then clear contents of the range and then loop the code, in an effort to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Kind of LookUp

- The first Sub addresses your immediate case (`Bulk Density ...`).
- If you want to apply the same logic to other 'properties', edit the
  third Sub (which is calling the second Sub) to fit your needs.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub writeValueConst()

    Const CheckString As String = "Bulk Density"
    Const CheckCellAddress As String = "F6"
    Const Searchstring As String = "Moisture Content"
    Const SearchRangeAddress As String = "F3:F11"
    Const ColumnOffset As Long = 1
    Const WriteCellAddress As String = "M20"
    
    Dim cel As Range
    If Range(CheckCellAddress).Value = CheckString Then
        For Each cel In Range(SearchRangeAddress).Cells
            If cel.Value = Searchstring Then
                Range(WriteCellAddress).Value _
                  = cel.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    End If

End Sub

Sub writeValue(ByVal CheckString As String, _
               ByVal CheckCellAddress As String, _
               ByVal Searchstring As String, _
               ByVal SearchRangeAddress As String, _
               ByVal WriteCellAddress As String, _
               Optional ByVal ColumnOffset As Long = 1)

    Dim cel As Range
    If Range(CheckCellAddress).Value = CheckString Then
        For Each cel In Range(SearchRangeAddress).Cells
            If cel.Value = Searchstring Then
                Range(WriteCellAddress).Value _
                  = cel.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    End If

End Sub

Sub writeDensities()
    Dim Series(1) As Variant
    
    ' If you add or remove, you have to adjust the previous number after Series.
    Series(0) = Array("Bulk Density", "F6", "Moisture Content", _
                      "F3:F11", "M20", 1)
    Series(1) = Array("Dry Density", "F8", "Degree of Compaction", _
                      "F3:F11", "M21", 1)
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(Series)
        writeValue Series(j)(0), Series(j)(1), Series(j)(2), _
                   Series(j)(3), Series(j)(4), Series(j)(5)
    Next j

End Sub
```